# develop several node.js based application on the single windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting

Currently I'm implementing 2 node.js application. Backend system and Angular based frontend app who consume backend via API. But I faced with a problem - how to manage this correctly?

Because to avoid CORS both backend/client should be hosted in single domain (but different subdomains) and listen the same port.

Could anyone share his experience how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I will use `express.vhost` it is from `connect.vhost`:

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html

```
connect()
  .use(connect.vhost('sub.domain.com', subApp))
  .use(connect.vhost('domain.com', aap))
```